# Importing Keras raises numpy exceptions

Tags: python, numpy, keras

Hi I am trying to set up keras with a code that starts like this:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
import lstm, time #helper libraries
```

And it brings me the following error messages:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb
>
> ---
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>
> ---
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
>
> ---
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use the checkmark next to the answer rather than edit the question title

Answer (score 3):

Try installing it again:

```
pip install -U numpy
```